# How to correct sorting orders using Jquery Data table

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I am currently using the Jquery Plug [DataTables](http://datatables.net/) I am trying to figure out i can display my data from desc to asc. I have checked through the documentation i can not find anything thing clear that enables me to solve this problem. i've also added a link to my site here

I have a added a snippet of my JS here

```
$(".sortable").DataTable({order: asc});
```

Comment: Here is an example from the official website of Datatables : http://datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/basic_init/table_sorting.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the documentation of [order option](http://datatables.net/reference/option/order) , the value of order option has to be array of arrays

> The order must be an array of arrays, each inner array comprised of two elements

```
 $(".sortable").DataTable( {
    "order": [[ x, "asc" ]]
} );
```

where **x** is the index of the column that you want to order by

Answer (score 0):

From [their docs](https://datatables.net/examples/basic_init/table_sorting.html):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').DataTable( {
        "order": [[ 3, "desc" ]]
    } );
} );
```

Columns are ordered using 0 as the index for the first column on the left.

For multi-column sorting, you could have something like:

```
order: [[ 3, 'desc' ], [ 0, 'asc' ]]
```

Comment: Interesting, I get voted down but no comments as to why (I am quoting the docs!) - anyone care to explain?

Answer (score 0):

You code is close, as far as the example you have shown, the issue is that the order needs to be an array, not only the string 'asc' and DataTable should be dataTable:

```
$(".sortable").DataTable({order: asc});
```

should be:

```
$(".sortable").dataTable({
    "order": [[0, 'asc']]
});
```

[Link to order docs](http://datatables.net/reference/option/order)

Comment: That's incorrect answer, there is [`order`](http://datatables.net/reference/option/order) option that you've missed.

Comment: my bad, will edit, I wrote that too hastily, thanks!